# SocketCan Bridge error when connecting multiple nodes to bus

Tags: ros, can, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am attempting to use the socketCAN bridge from ros_canopen to communicate with two motor drivers front and rear on my robot. I am able to succesfully communicate with one of the motor drivers no problems at 125Kb and get no errors from this. The problem is when I wire the second motor driver onto the CAN bus i get this error here printed 4 times after a random amount of time.

```
[ERROR] [1520931505.862666540]: Error: controller problems;, asio: Success
```

Followed by the warning:

```
[ WARN] [1520931505.863486242]: Received frame is error: 20000000#0008000000000000
```

To me this seems like the two motor drivers on the CAN bus are trying to write over the top of each other as the address and message does not make sense. Is this likely to be the issue or should I be looking elsewhere?

On the linux end we are using an odroid xu4 with an mcp2515 board for the can bus communication.
Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Callum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285224/socketcan-bridge-error-when-connecting-multiple-nodes-to-bus/) by [callum91](https://answers.ros.org/users/33701/callum91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error frame [suggests](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils/blob/master/include/linux/can/error.h#L70) that your
CAN device has problems with sending out data (TX error reach warning level).

Did you [terminate](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/9759/en/) the CAN bus properly? Have you checked your [bus load](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/canbusload.1.html)?

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0